# Publishing from Visual Studio to Azure - Unable to create publish profile

Tags: azure, visual-studio

I am having problems publishing a web application from Visual Studio to Azure. I think that this might be something to do with the permissions on my account, as I have published using a different account (for a different company) from the same computer with no problem.

The error I get is:

[image]

I should make the following points:

- We do have an Azure account that I use this Microsoft account to access and have permission to create resources on it. I was also logged into the Azure portal on this account when trying to publish.
- I am signed into Visual Studio with this account.
- When I click on 'Sign In', I am taken through a login procedure (account name and password) then dumped straight back on the same screen with no change shown and no message indicating what happened.
- I get this error message when I click on finish

Could anyone please give me some idea what is failing here? In particular:

(1) Is this possibly because VS thinks I am not logged into an Azure account?

(2) Is the lack of any message on the sign-in procedure a bug?

(3) What exactly is 'publish profile' and why would it fail?

I should also point out that I have seen the similar stack overflow question at [Unable to create publish profile - Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635490/unable-to-create-publish-profile-azure) but I found nothing useful there.

Comment: I've posted a reply to the other question which might solve the problem for others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635490/unable-to-create-publish-profile-azure The solution for me was to update Visual Studio and install the "Azure development" workload.